# How to create button inside collapsible content panels and make the content visible and hide inside it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I've done collapsible content panels from this link http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ and what i need is? Inside the section1 content panel there will be only two buttons (yes and no). So when I click yes button, the two buttons disappear and some content should be loaded inside into section1 content panel. How to do this task? This is built with twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Create two buttons, the following code is for one button, but you can work out the rest and do what you want with the remaining button.

```
$('.yesbutton').click(function({
    $(this).hide();
    $('.nobutton').hide();
    $('.supersneakyhidingcontent').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On your button click event you can do as BeatAlex stated along with loading your content dynamically either from a template and/or datasource:

```
$('.button').click(function({
    // hide buttons

    // load content
    $.ajax({
         url: '/controller/action',    // path to controller or datasource
         type: 'POST',
         data: JSON.stringify(data),   // data to pass to server (format as needed)
         contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }).done(function (data) {          // data is what your return from server
        // execute code here to fill your selector
    }).fail(function (data) {
        // take action in case of failure
    });
});
```

If you loading data dynamically of course you may want to wrap your ajax calls in a global function. I do this and pass a callback function to it that I execute on done. This also allows me to have a more global error presentation to the user on fail.

One other suggestion that we are using with bootstrap that I really like because it takes a way alot of the JQuery selector writing is using Observables and MVVM. We do this with bootstrap and have had great success in our Single Page App using Bootstrap. We are using the free version of Kendo UI Web. Hope this helps.

[Kendo UI Observable Framework](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observable) |
[MVVM in Kendo UI Walkthrough](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/mvvm-in-kendo-ui)